# Is there any Ruby library that supports HTTP Digest?

Tags: ruby, http-digest

Is there any Ruby library that supports HTTP Digest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[httparty](http://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) has just been patched to work correctly with HTTP Digest.

Answer (score 0):

The [httpclient](http://github.com/nahi/httpclient) library on github seems to support it although I have not used it myself.

If you are developing a Rails application then Digest is now supported within the framework.